# Force application to run off of discreet vs built-in GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

So I have a Dell XPS 15 with a NVidia 960M GPU. This is just below recommended specs but from my understanding should still be able to work with the HTC Vive.

Using the Nvidia control panel you can tell any application to use the high performance discreet GPU, which is what I have done. 
What is most confusing is that when I run the test, I can confirm that the discreet card is being used, but at completion, the performance test suggests upgrading my gpu and only lists the internal Intel HD530.Funky!

Comment: You can disable the on-board GPU in the BIOS while you test, but this will need a reboot (and another to re-enable it). Others may have a better alternative.

Comment: I am not familiar with this specific laptop, but most dual graphics laptops have a graphics utility that lets you assign certain graphics modes such as integrated or discreet (or Battery and High Performance) to specific applications. Also remember that many laptops by default disable the use of the discreet graphics if the A/C power is not connected.

Comment: please see my revised question